# SQL Server : select from multiple tables and calculate percentages

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have four tables and I would need to extract data from them to calculate the percentage

Table1

```
ID FK1 FK2
------------------
1  1   1
2  2   2
3  3   3
```

Table2

```
ID Name
------------------
1  L1   
2  A1
3  B
```

Table3

```
ID FK3
------------------
1  1    
2  2
3  3
```

Table4

```
ID Name
------------------
1  BA   
2  N    
3  CE
```

Now I need to get a Name from table4, which will be displayed as individual rows and then a Name from table2, which will be listed as individual columns and the value will then be a percentage of the record from table4:

```
Name   L1      A1       B
---------------------------
BA     20(%)   40(%)  40(%)
N      30(%)   20(%)  30(%)
CE     15(%)   15(%)  70(%)
```

Because there are links, I'll give an example of what question I have now

```
select t3.Name
from table1 t1 (nolock)
join table2 t2 (nolock) on t1.FK1 = t2.ID
join table3 t3 (nolock) on t1.FK2 = t3.ID
join table4 t4 (nolock) on t2.FK3 = t4.ID
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Thank you very much

Comment: Why do you have 4 `NOLOCK` query hints? You *do* understand the implications of using such a query hint, correct? If you *really* are happy with potentially erroneous data, why use 4 hints, and not change the entire isolated level of the query?

Comment: Not clear to me what the percentage calculation is. Describe how you would calculate with pencil and paper. How do you arrive at 20% for the BA/L1 cell?